# Inscribed parallelogram with center of mass O

Tags: geometry, discrete-geometry

X is a convex polygon with center of mass O. Prove that there exists an inscribed parallelogram with center of mass at O.

Hi guys, im have a hard time with this problem. I tried to use rombus' theorems to solve but could not do that. Please any help to solve?

Comment: Theorem 5.10. [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.145.1346&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: How i can use that theorem